# Lambda function with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, lambda

I'm trying to understand how `lambda` functions work, so far I had no success applying it to a dataframe.
I'm trying to check `if dtype == 'int64'` convert it to `Int64`, if only someone could give me a general example of how those functions work not an answer specific to this question so that I can really understand it and practice, I would really appreciate it.

I tried something like this but I I'm pretty sure that it doesnt even make any sense

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.astype('Int64') for col in df.columns if col.dtypes == 'int64')
```

Comment: Please post what you tried, and whatever details you can about what was wrong with it.

Comment: @ScottHunter I added one I tried but as I said I have no idea how to use the in general, I don't wont someone writing the code for me, I want someone who would like to help me understand so that I can do it myslef, Thanks

Comment: you can use `df.select_dtypes('int64')` then typecast it

Answer (score 1):

A lambda function is just an anonymous function. For instance,

```py
my_func = lambda x: int64(x)
```

is exactly equivalent to

```py
def my_func(x):
    return int64(x)
```

It sounds like maybe your question is more about converting the types held in a dataframe to int64? In that case `df.astype('int64')` should do the trick.

Comment: well yes I do wnat to know how to select columns with specific dtype and convert to another but i'm more inrterested in function like the one I provided above p.s.(I know that mine probably makes no sense, I'm talking generally functions that look like this I just don't understand them)